# Adding 15K tasks to Jenkins build queue

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, queue, parameterized

I have a Jenkins server with about 50 slaves attached.
I'm trying to do some stress test on Jenkins Build Queue because I haven't found any documentation about it.

I have a simple parameterized job with just one step, BRANCH and COUNT are the job parameters. The job sleep for a random amount of time between 10 to 30 seconds :

```
#bash

RESULT="/path/to/results_dir/$BRANCH/$BUILD_ID.txt"
SEC=$(shuf -i10-30 -n1)
sleep $SEC
echo -e "$NODE_NAME\t$BUILD_TAG\t$SEC\t$COUNT" > $RESULT
```

I would like to run this job 15K times.
At first I tried to use Jenkins REST API from command line :

```
for c in $(seq 1 15000); do curl -X POST http://<server ip>:8080/job/TEST_SIMPLE/buildWithParameters --data-urlencode "token=TEST" --data-urlencode "BRANCH=<branch name>" --data-urlencode "COUNT=${c}"; done
```

But after an hour only 4K tasks were submitted, so I killed the loop and purge Jenkins build queue.

My second try was to use another job which trigger this 'TEST_SIMPLE' job by using system groovy script and calling 'job.scheduleBuild' API. It is currently running for 1.5 hours and submitted only 8K tasks out of 15K.

It seems that tasks are added to the queue only when a slave takes one from the queue

The purpose of this effort is to replace a very old executor/dispatcher for our test suite which contain many many tests (~ 15K) and I doing a POC with Jenkins because we are already using it for our builds and to run this old executor.

So my questions are:
1. Is there a limit on the size of the build queue ?
2. Is there a way to submit so many requests very fast ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly you would like to know:

1. Is there a limit to the build queue?
2. How can I submit lots of requests to Jenkins very fast?

Let me answer the second question first.  To submit requests faster you can use parallel `xargs` with `curl`.  This will allow you to use multiple threads to submit your `curl` requests.

```
seq 1 20 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I cnt curl -X POST http://<server ip>:8080/job/TEST_SIMPLE/buildWithParameters --data-urlencode "token=TEST" --data-urlencode "BRANCH=<branch name>" --data-urlencode "COUNT=cnt"
```

The `xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I cnt` command passes arguments one at a time (`-n 1`) to `curl` using the variable name 'cnt' (`-I cnt`) in parallel (`-P 10` with 10 threads).

Depending on the the number of processors on the machine you use to generate load you could use a very high number of threads.  Go too high and your ability to generate load will drop off as the threads compete for processor. On most modern laptops I would start at 50 and push it till the fans sounded like a jet engine, but thats just me.

As far as the queue limit, it will definitely be bounded by memory and disk but I would have to dig into source to see if there are other constraints.